# System resets after swap memory is consumed partially

Tags: sles, swap

My System resets even if swap memory is consumed partially. What can be the reason for this?

How can I can overcome this situation?

I am using Suse Linux Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1):

> What can be the reason for this?

Lots - mostly hardware related.

> even if swap memory is consumed partially

Sounds like a red-herring - unless its only ever happenning at a certain amount of swap usage. Replace your existing swap (pasrtition or file) with a new swap file - if problem still occurs then its probably not to do with the swap / disk.

C.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an extensive hard drive test. If you wish to delve even further into troubleshooting this you could redirect output to a serial console and watch what happens when the server reboots (google is your friend here).

HTH